# Google Appengine Remote API auth

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth

I've been using the remote API for google appengine for a couple years. Several months ago I updated to the Oauth2 authorization approach as documented here and everything has worked fine for months.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi

Today I ran into the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
You must be logged in as an administrator, or access from an approved application.
```

I don't understand what changed or how to resolve it. I've made sure that I'm logged in with the correct account by using the following command.

```
gcloud auth login
```

Which successfully logs me in.

The account that I use to login, is a google apps account which I suspect is the problem. I think the integration of google apps accounts with appengine has changed based on this old, but seemingly related question.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1462

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a @gmail.com account instead of my Google app account. It looks like changes are being made to google app accounts to move functionality into the Google cloud platform.

Although I have things working again, I would prefer to use my username and password associated with by app domain and it's not clear how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a myriad of problems, then switched from my Google Apps (Dasher) account to my @gmail account, and everything worked.

I suspect (but can't prove) that this is related to the turndown of ClientLogin on 12-Apr-2016.